# Best policy for "article's photo" in a magazine online?

Tags: photo-management

I'v design a db for magazine online,foe each article i will have 3 photos in different size ,first i select one photo and then must make another 2 photos with resizing,if i want that handel this by hand it is very difficult,what is your suggestion?i use mysql+php  and is there any cms in this regard?

thanks

Comment: just make sure to NOT store the images in the database, store a reference to them instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ImageMagick on the server to create the other two images.

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php
- http://www.evolt.org/node/55650

Comment: it is years that i use firework ,do you think that  ImageMagick is better and more simple?

Comment: yes , i read on php.net as my underestanding it doesn't need that i do manually and for other images i resize with php.

Comment: With imagemagick, you just need to call `convert in.jpg -resize 400x400 out.jpg` and it's done.  You can control the type of resizing if you want.  I have never used firework, but imagemagick is very simple. More info: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/

Comment: There is a question for me,i have a main in.jpg in its folder and want to resize it in several points on my site and i call "convert in.jpg -resize 400x400 out.jpg"  so these out.jpg save on my site? or a copy of in.jpg resize and send to user that request that page?

Comment: When you call convert on the server, the output jpeg will be on the server, but you could copy it to a folder in your webroot and then put an img tag in the page that uses it.

Comment: "output jpeg will be on the server" does it mean that with each request of a page by a user one copy creat?  or each copy goes to a temp folder and after a while will be kill?

Comment: It's up to you and how you code it.  You could check to see if the result file exists and skip it.  Probably the best thing to do is to create the 2 other images right after the original is uploaded -- then they are already there when the request comes in.